# Docker file RUN multiple sed commands

Tags: docker, sed, docker-compose, dockerfile

I am trying to change several configuration items in a single file that is part of an existing Docker image using the following RUN command:

```
RUN sed --in-place '/start_rpc:/ s/false/true/g' /etc/cassandra/cassandra.yaml &&\
    sed --in-place '/broadcast_rpc_address:/ s/172.17.0.2/192.168.1.248/g' /etc/cassandra/cassandra.yaml &&\
    sed --in-place '/listen_address:/ s/172.17.0.2/192.168.1.248/g' /etc/cassandra/cassandra.yaml &&\
    sed --in-place '/seeds:/ s/172.17.0.2/192.168.1.248/g' /etc/cassandra/cassandra.yaml
```

I am sure the multiple sed commands are fine as I can run them on the host's console and achieve the 4 changes I am trying to execute.

The `docker build` does not show any errors and, in fact, it generates a new image. However, when I run the container and login to it, I can see that only the first of the four replacements took place.

I have already tried several combinations, including a compound sed such as:

```
RUN sed --in-place '/start_rpc:/ s/false/true/g; /broadcast_rpc_address:/ s/172.17.0.2/192.168.1.248/g; /listen_address:/ s/172.17.0.2/192.168.1.248/g; /seeds:/ s/172.17.0.2/192.168.1.248/g' /etc/cassandra/cassandra.yaml
```

And also four individual RUN commands.  In all cases the result was the same: `start_rpc` is changed to `true` but not one of the other IP addresses gets changed.

Does anyone have any idea what could be wrong here and, if so, why `docker build` does not report something useful (and preferably fails)?

Comment: Could it be that a posterior step overwrites the file you are modifying?

Comment: Try `&& \ ` instead of `&&\ `

Comment: How are you verifying this?  Are you potentially running the container with some sort of volume mount to inject a `cassandra.yaml` file, or possibly a previous step has declared a `VOLUME /etc/cassandra` that prevents the directory from being modified?

Comment: @poshi There are no posterior steps.  I only need to modify 4 entries in the configuration for now.

Comment: @DavidMaze I don't have any volume mounts and no previous steps.  I am verifying by starting the container then logging into it and grepping the file looking for the items that should have changed. The really strange thing here is that the first items gets changed correctly from false to true but the other 3 simply do not happen.

Comment: @Paolo I shall try that in a minute but remember that I have also tried a compound `sed` which did not contain a single `&&\` and it still failed in the same way.

Comment: In that case, check that the modification is really done. Just after the `sed` command, in the same line (separated by `&&`), visualize the file and check that the modifications are really applied. If they are, the file is being modified somehow afterwards; if they are not applied, the issue is in the `sed` commands.

Comment: What happens if you change the order of the modifications? It is always the first the one applied? Or is it always the same modification regardless of the order in which it appears??

Comment: @Poshi I have changed the order and reduced to just two commands.  I have also trimmed the IP addresses back to just the first 3 digits.  Now the first replacement fails and the second succeeds.  I have been staring at these patterns for a long time and I cannot spot anything that could explain why sed ignores the replacements with IP addresses.  Sed version is 4.7 in all environments.  I am on Docker 20.10.12.  Base image I am using is `sudo docker pull cassandra:3.11`.  Is anyone able to reproduce this?

Comment: I'm not a Docker expert, but if I'm not wrong, you can open a terminal inside that Docker image, right? Try to run those commands in that docker terminal. I cannot see any reason why some substitution fails. After the first failure, the following substitutions won't run, which could explain why you only see one working.

Comment: @Poshi Thank you for your persistence on this one. Yes, I can confirm that I always login to the container to check whether the changes are executed or not.  I have just executed each command from within the container and every single `sed` does exactly what is expected.  But I believe the `docker build` is running outside the intended container.  Also, one can run `docker history --no-trunc <image_id>` to see exactly how the image was built.  The output shows me that all commands were run (presumably successfully) but the result is not what I expected.  I am a Docker newbie, any help welcome

Comment: If you can see the output of the commands in `RUN`, try to see the contents after each `sed` invocation and check which invocations change something and which not: `sed 'blahblah' file && cat file && sed 'moreblah' && cat file...`.

Comment: @Poshi I don't know how to display the output of the commands but I tried to redirect the output to another file instead. I also added a few more `sed` commands to replace other items that are not IP addresses. Replacements that have nothing to do with IP addresses **work** no matter how many of them I have.  Now, with IP address replacements I am going crazy. I first copied the original to a temp file and the mere `cp` command resulted in a slightly modified file.  I am going to create a separate entry in Stackoverflow to avoid confusion and will link it here once done.

Comment: Your link in the update points to this same question. BTW, I have no more ideas, but if a `cp` also "modifies" the file... the issue does not have anything to do with `sed`. There's something else going on.

Comment: **UPDATE with corrected link**: out of my multiple experiments, an apparent simpler issue came up which I documented here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71449623/docker-compose-giving-unexpected-result-for-a-simple-cp Maybe if we can solve the simpler one we can get a hint for how to solve this one.

Answer (score 0):

The answer to these problems can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71449623/docker-compose-giving-unexpected-result-for-a-simple-cp) but, in a nutshell, once the container starts, additional scripts are run to complete the set up of Cassandra and IP addresses are the typical type of configuration that can only be discovered once the container starts.