# Docker compose giving unexpected result for a simple cp

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I am a Docker newbie and in trying to solve a [different problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71429581/docker-file-run-multiple-sed-commands) I came across a very disconcerting behaviour that I would love someone more knowledgeable to explain for me:

**How I got there:**

```
$ sudo docker pull cassandra:3.11
```

Create a fresh Dockerfile in current directory with following content:

```
# First attempt at changing Cassandra configuration file
FROM cassandra:3.11
MAINTAINER joe.bloggs@gmail.com
RUN cp /etc/cassandra/cassandra.yaml /etc/cassandra/cassandra_copy.yaml
```

Generate new image, run container and log into container:

```
$ sudo docker build -t cassandra_r:3.11 .
$ sudo docker run -p 9042:9042 --rm --name cassandra -d cassandra_r:3.11
$ sudo docker exec -it cassandra bash
```

Change into the directory to inspect ownership and compare the two files involved in the copy:

```
$ sudo docker exec -it cassandra bash
root@f886ceffa190:/etc/cassandra# ls -ltr
total 216
-rw-rw-rw- 1 cassandra cassandra   291 Feb  7 13:01 README.txt
-rw-rw-rw- 1 cassandra cassandra  1603 Feb  7 13:01 metrics-reporter-config-sample.yaml
-rw-rw-rw- 1 cassandra cassandra  3809 Feb  7 13:01 logback.xml
-rw-rw-rw- 1 cassandra cassandra  1195 Feb  7 13:01 logback-tools.xml
-rw-rw-rw- 1 cassandra cassandra  9956 Feb  7 13:01 jvm.options
-rw-rw-rw- 1 cassandra cassandra  2757 Feb  7 13:01 hotspot_compiler
-rw-rw-rw- 1 cassandra cassandra  6360 Feb  7 13:01 cqlshrc.sample
-rw-rw-rw- 1 cassandra cassandra  2082 Feb  7 13:01 commitlog_archiving.properties
-rw-rw-rw- 1 cassandra cassandra  1358 Feb  7 13:01 cassandra-topology.properties
-rw-rw-rw- 1 cassandra cassandra  1200 Feb  7 13:01 cassandra-rackdc.properties
-rw-rw-rw- 1 cassandra cassandra   148 Feb  7 13:01 cassandra-jaas.config
-rw-rw-rw- 1 cassandra cassandra 12699 Feb  7 13:01 cassandra-env.sh
-rw-rw-rw- 1 cassandra cassandra 18250 Feb  7 13:01 cassandra-env.ps1
drwxrwxrwx 2 cassandra cassandra  4096 Mar  7 20:09 triggers
-rw-r--r-- 1 cassandra root      61211 Mar 12 11:54 cassandra_copy.yaml
-rw-rw-rw- 1 cassandra cassandra 61213 Mar 12 11:54 cassandra.yaml
root@f886ceffa190:/etc/cassandra# diff cassandra.yaml cassandra_copy.yaml
431c431
<           - seeds: "172.17.0.2"
---
>           - seeds: "127.0.0.1"
618c618
< listen_address: 172.17.0.2
---
> listen_address: localhost
632c632
< broadcast_address: 172.17.0.2
---
> # broadcast_address: 1.2.3.4
695c695
< rpc_address: 0.0.0.0
---
> rpc_address: localhost
714c714
< broadcast_rpc_address: 172.17.0.2
---
> # broadcast_rpc_address: 1.2.3.4
```

**Observations**

The copy command clearly worked, the copy has the right ownership but it ended up in the wrong group. No harm so far.

**Question**

Since there is only a copy command, why on earth some IP addresses got changed and a couple of entries even acquired a # character to comment them out?  What exactly is causing this rather unexpected behaviour?

**More**

Not that I think this should matter but this is where I am running all this:

```
$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 21.10
Release:    21.10
Codename:   impish
```

Answer (score 2):

The `cassandra` image has an *entrypoint wrapper script* that does this first-time setup.  This is a fairly common pattern where an image's `ENTRYPOINT` is a shell script that does some amount of setup work, and then ends with `exec "$@"` to run the image's `CMD`.  All of the things you observe are happening in that wrapper script, which happens when the container starts up; so after your `RUN cp ...` command in the Dockerfile.

---

The [Docker Hub `cassandra` image page](https://hub.docker.com/_/cassandra) has links to the current Dockerfiles.  At [the end of the Dockerfile](https://github.com/docker-library/cassandra/blob/ac4975fcd60b47291ca4772d8cce8047f10674b4/4.0/Dockerfile#L172-L181) you can see the setup for the entrypoint wrapper script

```sh
COPY docker-entrypoint.sh /usr/local/bin  # executable, starts with #!/bin/sh
ENTRYPOINT ["docker-entrypoint.sh"]       # must be JSON-array form
CMD ["cassandra", "-f"]
```

The [`docker-entrypoint.sh`](https://github.com/docker-library/cassandra/blob/ac4975fcd60b47291ca4772d8cce8047f10674b4/4.0/docker-entrypoint.sh) is next to the Dockerfile in the GitHub repository.  That has two relevant blocks: it [changes ownership of many files](https://github.com/docker-library/cassandra/blob/ac4975fcd60b47291ca4772d8cce8047f10674b4/4.0/docker-entrypoint.sh#L10-L15) to a `cassandra` user if it's running as root, and it [rewrites various IP addresses](https://github.com/docker-library/cassandra/blob/ac4975fcd60b47291ca4772d8cce8047f10674b4/4.0/docker-entrypoint.sh#L66-L82) as you're observing.

An interesting variant you might try is

```sh
sudo docker run --rm -it cassandra_r:3.11 /bin/bash
```

This will start an interactive shell as the main container process instead of Cassandra, so you don't need `docker exec`.  But more specifically, it replaces the `CMD` with effectively `CMD ["/bin/bash"]` but leaves the `ENTRYPOINT` intact.  This means the wrapper will run but then launch the shell instead of Cassandra as its last step.

The specific thing that makes this interesting is that both of the referenced sections of the entrypoint script have guards `if [ "$1" = "cassandra" ]`.  The `ENTRYPOINT` gets passed the `CMD` as arguments, so here `$1` is the first word of the command; since it's not `cassandra` none of this setup will happen.

Similarly, if you use `docker run -u` to run the container as some non-root user, you should see the `chown` step doesn't happen, but the IP address setup will (assuming the user you select has permissions to write the configuration file).

Comment: Wow, thank you for that @David! What you are saying makes sense but it also makes it harder to customize a container if what you need to change is also manipulated by the entry point wrapper.  In fact, I am wondering how I could do that without creating a Cassandra image from scratch.  Thanks again!